# Assign google places details into php variable

Tags: php, google-places-api

I am using google places api to get some business details. I have looked at google and find the way to display the details on google map. What I also want to achieve is to assign the the details into php variables. Below code displays the details on the map;

```
  <script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -9999.9999, lng: 99999.99999},
          zoom: 1
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.getDetails({
          placeId: 'XXXXXXXXXX'
        }, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                'Telephone: ' + place.formatted_phone_number + '<br>' +
                'Website: ' + place.website + '<br>' +
                place.formatted_address + '</div>');
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    </script>


<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

What I want to be able to achieve is like the code below for example;

```
 <script>
    var a="Hello";
</script>
<?php 
    echo $variable = "<script>document.write(a)</script>"; 
?>
```

So to sum up, I want google places parameters to be assigned to php avriables so i can use them any way I want.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around, i found the answer in a different way. For anyone who may need it at some point/ Here is the code below

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACE_ID&key=API_KEY';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonContent = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$jsonContent['result']['name'];
$jsonContent['result']['formatted_phone_number'];
$jsonContent['result']['formatted_address'];
$jsonContent['result']['website'];
```

Hope it helps